# Lazy A* Implementation

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I am working on a toy RTS game, for path finding I am relying on A*, problem is alot of units are moving around causing calculated paths to become invalid which is causing wasted CPU cycles, I have to recalculate paths for those agents.

So I thought why not calculate the path lazily instead of calculating the whole path, I keep calculating it as I go along. A google search did not turned up much are there any implementations of lazy A* or any other graph search algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [the D* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%2a). It actually works better for this purpose.